# Graph implementation adjacency list vs set

Tags: data-structures, graph, linked-list, set

After reading about how to implement a graph it seems I have basically two options:

- [Matrix](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/12_1_AdjacencyMatrix_Repres.html)
- [Adjacency list](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/12_2_AdjacencyLists_Graph_a.html)

In order to decide which implementation to use [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79322/when-are-adjacency-lists-or-matrices-the-better-choice#answer-79326) can be useful.

When an `adjacency list` is used to implement a graph the **cost** to know if there is an **edge between two nodes** may take **linear time** (for those nodes connected to all nodes).

That make me wonder: Why not to use a [HashSet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-in-java/) instead of a [linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/) in order to keep the neighbors of a node?

This will give us **constant time** to know if there is an **edge between two nodes**. 
I'm sure must be a disadvantage using a `Set` instead of `Linked list` but I can't see it.

Comment: Could be because the space used for the `Set`? Reading https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-sethashset-in-java/ seems like a `HashMap` is used to implement the `HashSet` and reading https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/ ends up using an `array`, so we lose the advantage of the pointers when a `linked list` is used. Could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "list" is just a generic name. I've used a Set and it works perfectly well.

There is no specific reason to use a list instead of a set, here go through this link - [Graph using set](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-representations-using-set-hash/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you mean by "offers memory coherency"? What do you think about the comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964683/graph-implementation-adjacency-list-vs-set#comments-51964683 ?

Comment: I've updated the question because I was thinking in a `HashSet` instead on a `TreeSet` which keeps the order but has more time complexity to search an element. Anyway, it's interesting the implementation of a graph using the treeset. What do you think about using an implementation with a HashSet?

Comment: So TreeSet keeps order and HashSet doesn't so let's say we have to perform a dfs over all nodes of the graph, then in that case, whether it's HashSet or TreeSet, doesn't make much difference, my point being, what I feel is, it  depends on what kind of functionality you are trying to achieve using graph.

Comment: The differences in terms of big O are important. To know if there is an edge between two nodes takes constant time in a `HashSet`, log(n) time in a `TreeSet`, and linear time in a `LinkedList`. The complexity times also are different in an insertion/deletion. So yes, it depends of functionality you want, but in any case I don't see any benefit when a `LinkedList` is used. So I just want to know if exist any benefit (I suspect is a memory optimization, but I'm not sure)